# pycryptodome module cannot be imported as wheel

Tags: python

I downloaded **pycryptodome** python module wheel format file (*pycryptodome.whl*) from [here](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/#files)

Now when I try to **import** and use it as follows,

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
```

I get this **ImportError: No module named Crypto.PublicKey**

I have another module called **PyVMOMI** (*pyvmomi.whl*) where I do not see this problem, I can very well import any of its module files without any error.

Note: the directory where the ***.whl** file is located is set in the **PYTHONPATH** variable already

Answer (score 1):

You can't import `.whl` files as they just aren't meant to be imported directly. They're meant to be [*installed*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/) first (emphasis mine):

> A wheel is a ZIP-format archive with a specially formatted file name and the .whl extension. It contains a single distribution nearly as it would be **installed** according to PEP 376 with a particular installation scheme. Although a specialized **installer** is recommended, a wheel file may be **installed** by simply unpacking into site-packages with the standard 'unzip' tool while preserving enough information to spread its contents out onto their final paths at any later time.

That you can import the `PyVMOMI` module doesn't mean you're importing the corresponding `.whl` file. This package has been installed first.