# Module installed from wheel cannot be imported

Tags: python, installation, module, package

I created a Python library/ package/ module which needs to be used on another system.

To do this, I took my built .whl file to the system, created a new virtual environment with `venv`. I also installed all other required libraries along with jupyter-lab in the environment. I then started a notebook session with the environment activated.

```
python -m venv envName
envName\Scripts\activate

pip install libraryName
...
pip install jupyterlab
```

Then I checked the installation by running:

```
pip list
```

and

```
pip show <libraryName>
Name: libraryName
Version: 0.0.1
Summary: Physically-meaningful alloy-interaction based features for ML modelling
Home-page:
Author: My Name
Author-email: My Email
License:
Location: c/users/.../my python stuff/envName/lib/site-packages
Requires: numpy, pandas
Required-by:
```

both in the notebook and from the command line.

The module was listed with the correct details in both cases.

---

However, when I try to import the library, I get a ModuleNotFound error.

I have checked that I am running the notebook from the correct environment. I have also tried setting the current working directory is also in the folder from where the library was installed, and to the folder for the virtual environment, to no avail.

I know that the library itself is capable of working since it ran on my own system without issues, and am completely stumped. Neither Google, nor ChatGPT could find anything which solved the issue.

I have found some similar Questions such as [Module installs but cannot be imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045752/module-installs-but-cannot-be-imported), [pycryptodome module cannot be imported as wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51422441/pycryptodome-module-cannot-be-imported-as-wheel), and [Curses installed, but cannot be imported (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70625154/curses-installed-but-cannot-be-imported-python); but none of the solutions seem to apply to my situation.

The Python version is 3.9.12 running on a Windows 11 machine.